# show images related to product from an object list to Django Template?

Tags: python, django, database, django-views, django-templates

Here I am trying to display all the images related to a particular product in a popup. Here I am getting all the product template images list from the template table through the templateproductmapping table.

**models.py**

```
# this is the product table
class Product(models.Model):
    prod_ID = models.AutoField("Product ID", primary_key=True)
    prod_Name = models.CharField("Product Name", max_length=30, null=False)
    prod_Desc = models.CharField("Product Description", max_length=2000, null=False)
    prod_Price = models.IntegerField("Product Price/Piece", default=0.00)
    prod_img = models.ImageField("Product Image", upload_to='productImage/', null=True)

# this is the imageTemplate table where I am storing template images 
class ImageTemplate(models.Model):
    temp_id = models.AutoField("Template ID", primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    temp_img = models.ImageField("Template Image",upload_to='Template Images/', null=False)

# here in this table I am storing mappings of images to a product, so I can identify which image belongs to which product so I can use all the images related to a single product.
class ImageTemplateProductMapping(models.Model):
    imageTemp_p_map_id = models.AutoField("Template Image & Product Map ID", primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    template_img_id = models.ForeignKey(ImageTemplate, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        verbose_name="Image Template ID")
    prod_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Product Id")
```

**views.py**

```
def product(request, id):
    products = Product.objects.get(prod_ID=id)
    ImageTemplateProductslist = []
    try:
        ImageTemplateProductsmap = ImageTemplateProductMapping.objects.filter(prod_id=id)
        #here i am getting all the images related to a single product.
        ImageTemplateProductslist = [data.temp_id.temp_img for data in
                                     ImageTemplateProductsmap]
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    context = {"ImageTemplateProductslist": ImageTemplateProductslist}
    return render(request, "GalaxyOffset/product.html", context)
```

**product.html**

```
<div class="col-5 mr-4 mt-2">
    {% for s in ImageTemplateProductslist %}
    <!--Here in this image tag I want to show that images-->
    <img class="border border-secondary rounded my-2 mx-3" height="100"
                                                 src="{{s.url}}"
                                                 width="100"/>
    <br>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Can you help to solve this issue?

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: On the product template I have a popup and I want to display all the images related to that product in that popup for selection but I don't know how to get that images there, I have tried different options but none of them worked. Can you help me to figure out what I am doing wrong and what should I do and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is really a very silly mistake done by me where I haven't paid attention, in the ImageTemplate table I am using temp_id as a Primary Key, and in the ImageTemplateProductMapping table, I am passing template_img_id as a foreign key, and then using temp_id as a reference to fetch data from ImageTemplatte. That's why the code is not working for me. let me share my changed code again :

**models.py**

```
# this is the product table
class Product(models.Model):
    prod_ID = models.AutoField("Product ID", primary_key=True)
    prod_Name = models.CharField("Product Name", max_length=30, null=False)
    prod_Desc = models.CharField("Product Description", max_length=2000, null=False)
    prod_Price = models.IntegerField("Product Price/Piece", default=0.00)
    prod_img = models.ImageField("Product Image", upload_to='productImage/', null=True)

# this is the imageTemplate table where I am storing template images
class ImageTemplate(models.Model):
    temp_id = models.AutoField("Template ID", primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    temp_img = models.ImageField("Template Image",upload_to='Template Images/', null=False)

# here in this table I am storing mappings of images to a product, so I can identify which image belongs to which product so I can use all the images related to a single product.
class ImageTemplateProductMapping(models.Model):
    imageTemp_p_map_id = models.AutoField("Template Image & Product Map ID", primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    temp_id = models.ForeignKey(ImageTemplate, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        verbose_name="Image Template ID")
    prod_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Product Id")
```

**views.py**

```
def product(request, id):
    products = Product.objects.get(prod_ID=id)
    ImageTemplateProductslist = []
    try:
        ImageTemplateProductsmap = ImageTemplateProductMapping.objects.filter(prod_id=id)
        #here i am getting all the images related to a single product.
        ImageTemplateProductslist = [data.temp_id.temp_img for data in
                                     ImageTemplateProductsmap]
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    context = {"ImageTemplateProductslist": ImageTemplateProductslist}
    return render(request, "GalaxyOffset/product.html", context)
```

**product.html**

```
<div class="col-5 mr-4 mt-2">
    {% for s in ImageTemplateProductslist %}
    <!--Here in this image tag I want to show that images-->
    <img class="border border-secondary rounded my-2 mx-3" height="100"
                                                 src="{{s.url}}"
                                                 width="100"/>
    <br>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```